# C#: Running and Debugging a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am currently building a Windows Service with C# and I just can't figure out how to debug it.

---

I am building it and then registering with `installutil`:

```
> installutil MusicRepo_FileMonitor.exe

The Commit phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.
```

And as you can see above, it is supposedly being registered successfully, but I can't find it in `services.smc`.  I have also tried starting the service with `net start [ServiceName]` but it's telling me `The service name is invalid.` so I guess it's not finding it.

---

For the record, I'm on Vista and I'm developing the ws with .Net 3.5

---

**[Update]**

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711241/c-running-and-debugging-a-windows-service/711300#711300)

Comment: When you created the service, what was the service name information that you provided inside the properties of the service?

Comment: ServiceName: MusicRepoFolderWatcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further research, I realized that I had no Installer attached to the service, so the problem was now fixed by adding an Installer.

[Here](http://arcanecode.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/windows-services-in-c-adding-the-installer-part-3/) is the tutorial I used to add a Service Installer and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Try Task Manager and see if you see MusicRepo_FileMonitor.exe.  If not, then the service is definitely not running.

Alternatively, in Visual Studio, Debug > Attach to Process, check show processes from all users, and see if its there.